# Adding more than one to a variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, increment

So to add +1 to a variable you obviously use the code `varName++;` but if I want to increament it with a value of say, 4 on a click what how should that code look?

This is my exampel code:

```
var varName = 1;


$('.button').click(function{
   varName++;
});
```

Also, what would the code be to revert this? I.E decrease the variable with a specific value.

Comment: Also, you might want to declare var varName = 1; instead of using quotes around the value.

Comment: yes obviously it should be without qoutes :)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `+=` and `-=`:

```
$('.button').click(function{
    varName += 4; // increment by 4
    // varName -= 4; decrement by 4
});
```

I'd suggest you familirise yourself with the [JavaScript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Answer (score 1):

You can give it some mathematical way to work with it:

```
    var varName = 1;


    $('.button').click(function{
       varName+= 4;//increment by four
    });

    $('.button').click(function{
       varName-= 4;//decrement by four
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making functions?

like:

```
var varName = 1;

$('.button').click(function{
   var varName= increment_value(varName,4);//increment by 4
   //alert(varName);
   var varName= decrement_value(varName,4);//decrement by 4
   //alert(varName);
});

function increment_value(number,number_to_add){
     return number + number_to_add;
}

function decrement_value(number,number_to_deduct){
     return number - number_to_deduct;
}
```